# Mysql complex selection

Tags: mysql

How to select rows with exact subcats id's? For example i need to pick only rows which have subcat_id 2,6 or 2,4,5,7.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing123` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `subcat_id` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=223 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

REPLACE INTO `testing123` (`id`, `cat_id`, `subcat_id`) VALUES
    (170, 32, 5),
    (171, 33, 1),
    (172, 33, 7),
    (173, 34, 5),
    (175, 35, 2),
    (176, 36, 1),
    (177, 36, 2),
    (178, 36, 7),
    (179, 37, 2),
    (180, 37, 6),
    (184, 40, 2),
    (185, 40, 5),
    (186, 40, 6),
    (187, 41, 4),
    (188, 54, 2),
    (189, 54, 4),
    (190, 54, 5),
    (191, 54, 7),
    (192, 55, 6),
    (193, 56, 2),
    (194, 56, 6),
    (195, 57, 6),
    (196, 58, 1),
    (197, 59, 3),
    (198, 60, 6),
    (199, 61, 2),
    (200, 61, 6),
    (203, 63, 1),
    (204, 63, 6),
    (205, 64, 2),
    (206, 64, 6),
    (207, 65, 1),
    (208, 65, 2),
    (209, 66, 4),
    (214, 67, 1),
    (215, 67, 5),
    (220, 70, 1),
    (221, 70, 4),
    (222, 70, 5);
```

If i'm using OR or IN(), it's picking all rows, that have ANY one provided subcats, but i need to have exact matches only.

Table example provided for experiments.

Help! :)

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you mean by having subcat_id 2,6 or 2,4,5,7?  subcat_id is only a single integer, so no one row will ever have a subcat_id consisting of two or more.

Comment: Oh really? Watch the answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM testing123
 WHERE cat_id IN (SELECT cat_id
                    FROM testing123
                   WHERE subcat_id IN (2, 6)
                GROUP BY cat_id
                  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)


SELECT *
  FROM testing123
 WHERE cat_id IN (SELECT cat_id
                    FROM testing123
                   WHERE subcat_id IN (2, 4, 5, 7)
                GROUP BY cat_id
                  HAVING COUNT(*) = 4)
```

Note that `COUNT(*) = N` clause depends on how many subcats were enumerated in the `IN()`

Comment: Thanks mate! Just what i needed! Let me examine it to understand what you did. :)

Comment: Oh, so basically the trick is in COUNT(). If it's equal to provided subcats_ids count, then i't exact match, because there can be nothing else than provided ids. Thanks mate again! ;)

Comment: @Beck: yep. And this trick works only in cases if there are no duplicates (equal `cat_id + subcat_id` pairs)